# Best way to handle a winsock 10004 error

Tags: visual-c++, winsock

I am creating multiple sockets to send a UDP broadcast on the Client. On the Client I am also using a blocking recvfrom() call to obtain the IP addresses of the servers that reply. I decided to create a thread for each recvfrom() call because there could be no reply from servers, and that would leave me hanging. I am also creating another thread in order to keep track of the time and to exit the program. Say I put a time limit of 5 seconds. I will sometimes get the error 10004 -> http://support.ipswitch.com/kb/WSK-19980714-EM08.htm

Caused because i'm ending the program on a blocking call

Do you think it is fine to just detect if this certain error occurred  and do nothing. What is the best way of handling this?

ie.

```
if((recvfrom(socket, (char *)buffer, size, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr, &fromAddrLen)) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
   if(WSAGetLastError() == 10004)
      //do nothing
   else
      printf("\nrecvfrom() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use multiple threads to read from a single socket at the same time. Don't use a thread to handle your timeout.  All you need is a simple loop, maybe a timer.  To get around the blocking issue, either put the socket into non-blocking mode, or use `select()` with a timeout to know when it is safe to call `recvfrom()` without blocking, or use `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO)` to set a timeout on blocking reads.

Comment: I'm using threads to recvfrom() multiple different sockets (that were created depending on how many interfaces a machine has). Is that okay? When you suggested a loop, or maybe a timer, I implemented this using threads. What is the method you are thinking of? I'll look more into non-blocking mode as it seems the best option for me, but when I tried it I remember encountering an erroneous error that occurs and wasn't too sure on how to deal with it. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I ended up using Select() with a timeout as you said and got it working, which means I didn't need the thread timer / any timers anymore! Thank you again Remy.